# How to fetch more than 5000 item from SharePoint list?

Tags: list, sharepoint, records

I am trying to get more than 5000 items form SharePoint list. I am using below code:

```
var Url = appurl +"/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=ID,UserCountry,UserName/Name,UserName/Title,ModuleID/ModuleName,TopicID/TopicName,VisitCount,PolicyName,PolicyVisitCount,FAQName,FAQVisitCount,ReferenceName,ReferenceVisitCount&$top=5100&$orderby=VisitCount desc,UserName/Title asc &$expand=UserName/Title,ModuleID,TopicID&@target='" + hostWebUrl+ "'"
```

It works fine for less than 5000 records. But as soon as the number of records increase (more than 5000) it gives internal server error. Why is it doing this?

Comment: I am trying to fetch using $top=5100,it works fine till 5000 records.But the time records increases it gives internal server error

Comment: You can get as many items as we want if we make repeated calls to the same REST endpoint. Here is the nice article. please refer this --> https://srinivasananand.wordpress.com/2016/02/08/rest-api-querying-large-list/

Comment: I had tried by making repeated calls still getting the same error i.e internal server error

Comment: can you please share your code snippet....

Comment: look at the below code

Answer (score 0):

```
function fetchStatistics() {
var executor;
var appurl = appWebUrl.replace('#', '');
appurl = appWebUrl.replace('#wrapper', '');

var url = appurl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=ID,UserCountry,UserName/Name,UserName/Title,ModuleID/ModuleName,TopicID/TopicName,VisitCount,PolicyName,PolicyVisitCount,FAQName,FAQVisitCount,ReferenceName,ReferenceVisitCount&$orderby=VisitCount desc,UserName/Title asc &$expand=UserName/Title,ModuleID,TopicID&@target='" + hostWebUrl + "'",
jQuery.getScript("../_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js", getStatisticsDetails);
function getStatisticsDetails()
{
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appurl);
    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
             headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                var response = JSON.parse(data.body);

                if (response.d.__next) {
                    url = response.d.__next;
                    getStatisticsDetails();
                }
                bindDataGrid();
            },
            error:errorHandlerFetchStatistics
        }
    );
}
```

}

Comment: This is the code I am trying but not able to fetch more than 5000 records

Answer (score 0):

Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx

You need to index your list or make repeated calls to get more then 5000 item.
Also you can use `$filter` or `$top` in your `api` call to stay below 5000.